# Recursive function in Python returns only the last list value

Tags: python, sorting, recursion

I'm relatively new to programming and completely new to Python.
I'm currently practicing recursive functions.

I was trying to implement a simple sorting function that searches recursively for the lowest value of a given list and appends it to a new list.

However, when returning the list, it only returns the last (highest) value of the list.
What confuses me the most is that if I put a `print(result)` right before returning the result, the function prints the entire sorted list.

Here's my code.
PS: the function `smallesListIndex()` searches for the index of the lowest value of a given list.
Function:

```py
def recSort(liste, result=None):
    listIn = liste
    length = len(liste)
    smallestIndex = smallestListIndex(listIn)
    
    # To prevent creating a new list in every recursion, an intermediate list is to be created.
    if result is None:
        result = []
        
    if length == 1:
        result.append(listIn[smallestIndex])
        print(result)
        return result
        
    else:
        result.append(listIn[smallestIndex])
        listIn.pop(smallestIndex)      
        length -= 1
        # the intermediate list is to be given to the next recursion.
        return recSort(listIn, result)
```

Main:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    liste = [5, 2, 4, 8, 7, 10, 6]
    recSort(liste)
    print(liste)
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10] #  Output from the print function
[10] # Output from the main function
```

Comment: You return the sorted list but you never do anything with it `liste = recSort(liste)`

Comment: Oh that was it! Easier than I thought but that has been troubling me for quite a while now!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your function `recSort` return a list, and in your example, you don't use it.

Try, and see result:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    liste = [5, 2, 4, 8, 7, 10, 6]
    res = recSort(liste)
    print(res)
```

To explain, your function modifies the input list. That's why you only get one value.

If you don't want modification of your input, you can try `listIn = liste[:]` in your function.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your list `liste` is not the same because without using `copy` function, you're just creating references, so whatever you do to the reference, you do it to the original list
2. You're returning things from the `recSort` function, but you're not saving them anywhere. You can use in `main` something like `result = recSort(liste)` and then `print(result)`.

Answer (score 0):

If instead of `print(liste)` you do `print(recSort(liste))` then your code works.

Full corrected code below, also added my simple implementation of `smallestListIndex()` for the purpose of complete runnable example, and reformatted code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVJNT8MwDL3vV1jbpZVCxfgWUn/AJMQFbtMUBeptkVInSjLYfn3JR7t1gDjQU/rsZ/v52Rz8VtN11zW4BtcKpdD5J@n8ghrcF6p8nED4LPqdJVCVTHArKYTKySSyLL6/aOsLFVjIwq/bKV8/a8KerFI5qNMDM4S08dsIIWVimfBhgtQ9hH@ZKL1C65g@g1cNxuIHkod3i8JL2oAAws/UDCRBCNpDHHJnndTEQFCAPdoWGyk89okOvIY3zFWwqVJ9ue7lxHhUlAXljSS8huXqiA2cQV0N8@@EShiD1PQylmd6V@UxeWZsmLHInHJUI9mQ4fO2qBz@s1kOV0ab4iylHJUfmXYRZJ0GBb/Fv/a5kcGc@I55hHt/sqL6qet0SQsaTil4HXbKOYkWOY9bnXLeCkmcT3vF6YKiF7cMrhjcMHhgcM9gfsngrvdn2OjoWMMFd90X)

```py
def smallestListIndex(l):
    return l.index(min(l))

def recSort(liste, result=None):
    listIn = liste
    length = len(liste)
    smallestIndex = smallestListIndex(listIn)

    # To prevent creating a new list in every recursion, an intermediate list is to be created.
    if result is None:
        result = []
        
    if length == 1:
        result.append(listIn[smallestIndex])
        #print(result)
        return result
        
    else:
        result.append(listIn[smallestIndex])
        listIn.pop(smallestIndex)      
        length -= 1
        # the intermediate list is to be given to the next recursion.
        return recSort(listIn, result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     liste = [5, 2, 4, 8, 7, 10, 6]
     print(recSort(liste))
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
```